How does warm start work in simplex algorithm?
Can you please help me understand how warm start works in simplex algorithm?
Let's imagine that the simplex algorithm has found an optimal solution (left figure, point A). Then we added one new constraint and the optimal solution is now at point B (right figure).

Please give me a hint

Can the simplex algorithm get a new solution that is now at point B not from scratch but from point A? What confuses me is that after adding the new constraint, point A is no longer a vertex of the feasible region.
Intuitively, I feel that the simplex algorithm should return to the previous available vertex and from it go to the new vertex B, but I'm not sure if this is correct.

How can I know if a new constraint has thrown the previous solution out of the feasible region and I need to look for a new one? After all, not all new constraints will change the optimal solution.



After adding the new constraint, point A is "superoptimal" (optimal or better than optimal) but infeasible. The dual simplex algorithm starts from a superoptimal solution and, via a sequence of pivots, moves to a feasible solution that is feasible while preserving superoptimality, meaning the final solution is optimal. So in this case it will pivot its way from A to B. This is in contrast to the usual ("primal") simplex algorithm, which starts from a solution that is feasible but suboptimal and pivots its way to an optimal solution, preserving feasibility at each step. Solvers will frequently invoke dual simplex in this scenario, with a presumption (not always true, but likely) that dual simplex will need fewer pivots to get from A to B than primal simplex would to get from its starting point (presumably the origin in this case) to B.
As for the second question, just plug A into the new constraint and see if it violates the constraint.
